# XML multiple schema location

Tags: xml, xsd, schema

I have a XSD schema but I need it to be in two possible locations - one for development (i.e. my PC and one for productions.

Is there a simple mechanism to do this. For example development the XML will be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request xmlns="http://www.example.com/xml"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://dev.example.com/ Request.xsd\">
  <GetLocations />
</Request>
```

and production

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Request xmlns="http://www.example.com/xml"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/ Request.xsd\">
  <GetLocations />
</Request>
```

This is to enable the line in XSD `<xs:include schemaLocation="DataTypes.xsd" />` to pick up the correct file.

**ADDEMDUM**

Lets do a for exmaple

Suppose I use PHP `file_get_contents` to retrieve the XML file. Want to check it against a XSD file (via HTTP). In that file it has `<xs:include schemaLocation="DataTypes.xdf" />`. How does the PHP script know where to fetch this file from?

**AND THERE IS MORE**

I am doing the following

```
$xml = file_get_contents(<URL FOR XML FILE>);
$xsd = file_get_contents(<URL FOR XSD FILE>);

// The XSD has the include bit in it

$request = new DOMDocument();  
$request->loadXML($xml, LIBXML_NOBLANKS);
file_put_contents(<some temporary filename>, $xsd);
if (!$request->schemaValidate(<some temporary filename>))
{

etc...
```

The question is how to ensure that XSD file is picking up the correct `include` file. I have a two copies of the schema. One for production and the other that I am adding extra stuff to.

Comment: `xsi:schemaLocation` is just a hint - most tools allow you to also specify schemas outside the schema. But it depends on the tool - so it will help if say what tools you are using.

Comment: @13ren - Will be using a variety of tools. Just want the XSD/XML self-contained so it will not matter what tool is being used.

Comment: I think you're confused. The URL before the space in xsi:schemaLocation is a _namespace URI_, not necessarily an actual location. If you're using an actual XML file, and the XSD is in the same folder, then a relative path will probably work.

Comment: @JLRishe - How do I ensure that the `<xs:include` fetches the correct XSD file?

Comment: I don't have any experience with using `<xd:include>`, but one possible option is to (in code), modify or add the `xsi:schemaLocation` attribute to the document element before performing validation.  There is a chance that the treatment of the `<xs:include>`s is somewhat implementation-specific, but that may be worth a shot.

Comment: Some validators also allow providing the schema to the validator rather than having it automatically retrieved.  Not sure if the PHP libraries you're using provide that, but again, worth looking into.

Comment: Oh, if you want it to be the same schema (i.e. the same definitions), just have a copy of it. As @JLRishe said, the first string in the schemaLocation is actually the namespace - it's not actually an address, just looks like it. You should use the same namespace for both production and development (but you have different ones  `http://dev.example.com/` and `http://www.example.com/`). The second string is the address to fetch it - so have a copy of the schema in each installation. Does that make sense? It may help if you go back a step and describe what you want to achieve with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my knowledge..
THIS:

```
$xml = file_get_contents(<URL FOR XML FILE>);
$xsd = file_get_contents(<URL FOR XSD FILE>);
.............
...........
file_put_contents(<some temporary filename>, $xsd);
if (!$request->schemaValidate(<some temporary filename>))
```

will override this:

```
<Request xmlns="http://www.example.com/xml"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/ Request.xsd\">
```

And about

> how to ensure that XSD file is picking up the correct include file

There is no ready-made method to check and verify the filepath/URL of XSD file which is invoked in `schemaValidate`. What I would like to suggest is to quickly test it in dev environment (just to be sure).

Keep different copies in these two locations:
location1: A server path from where XML is picked, one XSD would reside there..

location2: XSD Path specified explicitly in your script, second one resides here..

one should have bad code (intentional) and other with a normal one which passes validation..

Parse your XML and check for errors.. The bad code obviously throws errors..

Repeat the same swapping the two XSD files..

By this you will know which one is playing the role :)

Hope it helps..

### Update:

tested on my asp.net site and here is my findings:

passed XML as stream input:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root
  xmlns="http://www.example.com/xml"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.example.com/ Request.xsd\">
  <branch>data</branch>
</root>
```

and so was XSD:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.example.com/xml" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="branch" type="xs:string" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

The Validation is failing with the following error:

```
Cannot load the schema for the namespace 'http://www.example.com/' - Could not find file 'c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\Request.xsd\'.. Line: 1 Column:40
```

With that means, it is looking for `Request.xsd` which is specified in `schemaLocation`. The relative path (`c:\windows\system32\inetsrv\`) is where service is running from.

Hope this helps..

Comment: You get the prize - the most useful answer among them (even though I am in the process of doing this). Will update the post with results for future people.

Comment: just got a bulb glowing in my head :) so posted. Glad you found it helpful, happy SOing :)

Comment: Please post your analysis after testing is done! I tested this behavior on .net platform.  It might be different with different platforms.. Eager to know :)

Comment: nah! I just tried to validate stream input XML against stream input XSD using asp.net. I got a different behavior ..I have updated my findings on that in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Explaining the behavior of `schemaLocation`: It(XML) pairs up with an XSD file which is residing in the same folder as it is (unless you have specified complete Filepath/URL). Now you know from where XSD file is being loaded.

Now in your example if you load XML by an XML parser, schemaLocation comes into picture, where the first URI reference in each pair is a namespace name, and the second is the location of a schema that describes that namespace.

If you load XML as Doc and validate against an XSD file giving a full path, `schemaLocation` will be overridden.

Answer (score 2):

The import element performs the same as include element. However,the import element allows you to access components from same/multiple schemas that may belong to different target namespaces.
here is syntax:

```
<import id="ID" namespace="namespace" schemalocation="filename"/>
```

The include element is used to include or refer to an external schema that is located at a definite address.
here is syntax:

```
<include id="ID" schemaLocation="anyURI" any attributes/>
```

The include element allows reference to any external schema that is defined in the context of the same target namespaces. The target namespaces for a schema is declared using the targetNamespace attribute of the schema element. The namespace attribute is not required in the include element because the target namespaces of the containing and conatined schemas are same.

schemaloaction behaviour is already explained by @infantpro'aravind'

Answer (score 1):

The PHP script won't know where the include is unless you parse the xsd file looking for the `schemaLocation` attribute, which may or may not be there because **it's entirely optional**.

When you import a schema into another schema you are not required to provide a path to the schema. Most XSD validators will look in same/sub-folders for any xsd file with namespace which matches the import statement. Some will even ignore the schemaLocation attiribute entirely.

Answer (score 1):

If the schema stays the same, you can host it on a public location, provide its absolute URI instead of a relative one, and everybody will be able to find it there.

If the schema changes (you say that you are adding "extra stuff" to the development version of the schema? What kind of stuff?) you are looking at the XML schema versioning problem. There is more to it than being able to find the schema, see [this document on xml schema versioning](http://www.xfront.com/Versioning.pdf) for some recommendations.